# Can not link second Google account to existing Firebase user (auth/provider-already-linked)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to link the second Google account to an existing Firebase user which has active Google Auth provider.

1. Sign in user using his first Google account:

   `auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())`
2. Then I'm trying to link the second Google account to the authenticated user:

   `user.linkWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())`
3. The linkWithPopup promise rejects with error:

   `{code: "auth/provider-already-linked", message: "User can only be linked to one identity for the given provider."}`

Does it mean that Firebase doesn't support linking of several different profiles of the same provider to one user? Is it going to be added soon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your error says, you cannot link more than one account to a single provider. You can have only one account per provider. We don't know if these options will be added in the future but for the moment this is how it works.